# Does Timetracker Update TFS?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have TFS2017 and I'm trying to generate a report for estimated time vs actual time.  We use Timetracker from 7pace and I was wondering if 7pace actually updates TFS tables.

In the Timetracker database there is a table called 
dbo.WorkLog with a field called PeriodLength.  This field shows the actual work the user assigned against the TFS task.

I'm wondering if any of the TFS ALM experts here know if Timetracker updates the TFS database anywhere.

I've read in few places that TFS does not show work completed but there is a [Tfs_Warehouse].[FactWorkItemHistory].[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_Completed work] value.  Maybe what I have read is for earlier versions of TFS.

I have reached out to the great folks at 7pace but they are on UK time and I was hoping to find an answer sooner.  I'm sure others have wanted to pull the same information from TFS and Timetracker and have learned the inner workings of how TFS and Timetracker work together.

Comment: it depends on the Process Template your Team project is configured with, whether the Completed work field is used. The CMMI and Agile template have this field enable, for example, the Scrum template doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing.  You seem like a knowledgeable ALM expert that I need in my Rolodex.

Comment: Looks like. You've found me then :)